# Soap Webservice Picking Wrong port number

Tags: java, web-services, soap, weblogic

I am deploying SOAP web service in weblogic 12c .It is picking the wrong    port number is there any way that we can manually set the port number .

```
<WL5G3N3:address location="https://XXX.xxx.com:11201/XXX/XXX">
    </WL5G3N0:port>
   </WL5G3N0:service>
```

It should be **11202**.We have **F5 URl** in which *http* is set to **11201** and *https* to **11202**. can anyone help what is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by setting the following system property at WLS startup script:

```
-Dweblogic.wsee.useRequestHost=true
```

Comment: WL5G3N3:address location="http://10.118.68.26:7015/ResponsysWSProxy/ResponsysWSProxy how does it picking 7015 can we specify our own port number.

Comment: the port 7015 must be your protocol HTTP or HTTPS, if not then a firewall before you WLS. In this situation you nee to use weblogic.wsee.useRequestHost property to wrapped the message (and be able to publish the correct port)